# Why can't I use sleep mode on my nc6220 running Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, sleep

I'm encountering a very odd issue with my [HP nc6220](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=447348&prodTypeId=321957&prodSeriesId=447371&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=2096).

Under both Windows XP and Xubuntu 12.04, I was able to put this machine into sleep mode. In Windows 7, however, I don't have the option to (notice the greyed-out "Sleep" option):

[image: sleep is greyed out]

I'm successfully able to hibernate this machine, so that *should* rule out issues with ACPI support, correct?

I'm stumped. **Why won't my nc6220 sleep under Windows 7, and what can I do to enable it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Output of running `powercfg /a` from the commandline? This should show you what sleep states are available, as well as troubleshoot why you can't go to Sleep mode.

It's possible as well that there's a device preventing it from sleeping. This should show you

Comment: Turns out that not having the graphics drivers installed _does_ affect a system's ability to sleep... >_>